# Excel Formula to Replace Numbers List with Default Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Using Office 365 Excel

On a regular basis I download a csv file from a remote application, the file contains a column of unique numbers. There could be 50 rows in this column.

I would like to substitute these rows of numbers with text. Each number corresponds to a value e.g.

```
0 = car
421 = bus
12 = boat
```

I have a predefined text list of each number and it's corresponding value. Currently I'm doing a find and replace on each number to replace it with it's corresponding value' but it's very inefficient.

Is there a more efficient way I can achieve this, with some sort of saved formula that I can run each time I download the csv? When I download the default csv ideally i'd like to run some formula that I have saved, rather than copy / paste a lot of things between sheets etc.

An example below of the default csv (showing only three rows for brevity);

```
+-----+----------------+
| id  | another column |
+-----+----------------+
| 0   | text           |
+-----+----------------+
| 421 | text           |
+-----+----------------+
| 12  | text           |
+-----+----------------+
| etc | etc            |
+-----+----------------+
```

I would like to run a formula that will replace the numbers with text like below.

```
+------+----------------+
| id   | another column |
+------+----------------+
| car  | text           |
+------+----------------+
| bus  | text           |
+------+----------------+
| boat | text           |
+------+----------------+
| etc  | etc            |
+------+----------------+
```

Any other suggestions are also welcome, however preferred method is via Excel.

Comment: If you happen to download this CSV then maybe just load it on PowerQuery and edit that specific column there? It probably won't be too hard to find out.

Comment: If you need to **replace** the value, you will need VBA or Power Query.  Or you could use a **LOOKUP** function in an extra column, and then replace the entire column.

Comment: Should have added when I download the default csv ideally i'd like to run some formula that I have saved, rather than copy / paste a lot of things between sheets etc. I'll look at both the suggestions above, thanks

Comment: The functioning of Excel formulas can be replicated in either VBA or Power Query.

Comment: I agree iwth @JvdV here - Power Query is perfect for this job. To get you started - look into the Get Data-menu under the Data-tab in excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only with Excel:
create a table into a new sheet/area where you can match ids and texts that you have to replace, i.e.:
( into a new sheet named 'MyTalbe')
A   |B
0   | car
421 | bus
12  | boat
...etc etc

into your db create a new colum with this formula:
index( 'MyTable'!B:B; match(A1; 'MyTable'!A:A; 0))